# How to change button text color of UIAlertView in iOS7?

Tags: ios7, uialertview, tintcolor

iOS7 introduced general tint-color. I think `UIAlertView` is also in the valid range, but actually tintColor doesn't look to work with `UIAlertView`. (for tappable button text color)

Is it possible to change the tint-color of alert view? If possible, how to change it?

Comment: Try to see [PMAlertController](https://github.com/Codeido/PMAlertController) a small library that allows you to substitute Apple's uncustomizable UIAlertController, with a beautiful and totally customizable alert.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot customize the appearance of alert views, it is impossible to change the buttons text color.

It is mentioned clearly in [UIAlertView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html):

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

**Update:**

The question was about iOS7, but now `UIAlertView` is deprecated, for `UIAlertController` you can simply change the view tint color:

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Gimme a break",
                                message: "For God sake its iOS7 question!",
                         preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

It is helpful also to check this question: [How to change UIAlertController button text colour in iOS9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)

Comment: @downvoter instead of this cowardly downvote, please tell us if we to achieve that using `UIAlertView`!

Comment: -(void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
should give you an option to edit ALL subviews, and inevitably the cancel button is a subview of that 'alertview' object. couldn't find it though..

Comment: You *shouldn't*. But you **can**.

Comment: Just come across this and it is so correct so +1. As for the other two comments, @eiran just **NO** very very bad advise you **Shouldn't** mess with the view hierarchy of a `UIAlertView` this is perfectly clear in the documentation. Doing so is a one fast track ticket to getting your application rejected by Apple. as for `WouterDS` The only reason you can add subviews is because `UIAlertView` is a subclass of `UIView` which allows the view hierarchy to be messed with so whilst you can you **SHouldn't**

Comment: This is possible: `[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`  However know that this tints all other tintable views too.

Comment: This is no longer true. Kevin Renella's answer works great for me: `[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIAlertView class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

Answer (score 2):

`UIActionSheet` can also change buttons' color by this way.

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: What do you mean with "this way"?

Comment: `[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];` can also change `UIActionSheet` buttons' color temporary

Comment: @answer-huang I copied "this way" from your comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers mentioning `[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];` should work but this code is doing way more than if should if you want to change only the `UIAlertView` tint color.

You can aim the component this way **on iOS < 9** :

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertView class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

And **on iOS >9** :

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIAlertView class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIAlertController class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: This is the same exact answer that you posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430459/4833705. You could have added a link to your previous question under the comments. Please don't post duplicate answers