# UIAlertView and UIButton has white buttons on white background

Tags: ios, objective-c

After upgrading the dev iPhone 5 to iOS 8.1, all of the buttons and default labels on UINavigationBars and UIAlertViews started to appear on screen with white text.

I tried to resolve the problem with:

```
// UIView tints
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UIAlertView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

This somehow solved the white buttons in most cases, but not all of them. I'm still having problems with the alert views appearing after receiving a notification in-app, with navigation bar buttons and labels.

Has anyone experienced this problem? And if possible has a solution?

[image: White buttons on UIAlertView]

Comment: by default it's blue try commenting [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Comment: you may try to change them globally [self.window setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; put the code in Application delegate

Comment: Radu, commenting that does not change the outcome. bpolat, tried that already with no success.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot customize the appearance of **UIAlretView**:

```
[[UIAlertView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Check Apple notes in [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html):

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is
> and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is
> private and must not be modified.

Possible Duplicate Question: [Change tint color of UIAlertview and UIActionsheet buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994993/change-tint-color-of-uialertview-and-uiactionsheet-buttons)

Comment: I am not trying to customize the appearance. In 8.1 button labels are white, for 8.0 is black. I'm trying to correct the difference.