# Change button title color in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uialertview

How can I change the color of the `UIAlertView` button title.

[image]

I want title `Ok` in red color.

Comment: Just a quick question is this iOS7 or iOS8? I'm not sure how they look in iOS8 but `UIAlertView`s have been replaced with `UIAlertController`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change button text color of UIAlertView in iOS7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193367/how-to-change-button-text-color-of-uialertview-in-ios7)

Answer (score 11):

Actually, you can change the tint color of the view of the UIAlertController in iOS8.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = ....
[alertController.view setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: This works if you subclass the UIAlertController and set the tintColor in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 9):

for Swift 3, use:

```
alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

***AFTER*** you present your alert controller

Comment: It worked for me before present the alert controller too

Comment: "AFTER" is not necessary. :)

Answer (score 6):

The Travis Weerts answer should work if you are using a `UIAlertController`. For those using `UIAlertView`, you can use the `UIView` appearance settings.

You can aim the alerts component this way **on iOS < 9** :

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertView class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

And **on iOS 9** :

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIAlertView class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIAlertController class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way (And easiest) is the following:

```
alert = UIAlertController(title: "foo", message: "foo", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction.... foo
...foo
alert.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
alert.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * alert.view.bounds.size.width
```

It gives also a plus effect of a "round faded orange circle" in the background.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Can't customize the appearance of alert views.

For more info  [UIAlertView Class Reference:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

For more info :
[How to change button text color of UIAlertView in iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193367/how-to-change-button-text-color-of-uialertview-in-ios7)

Comment: copyed answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193367/how-to-change-button-text-color-of-uialertview-in-ios7

Comment: @NitinGohel Whilst they look simpler I don't think it could have been put any other way since this is basically from the Apple documentation.

Comment: but true is that that is copied from i pasted link.

Comment: @NitinGohel I suppose but I really don't think it could have been put any other way, that one sentence does cover the whole thing and is definitely a correct answer, so I don't think it should just be a comment. I suppose it would been better if the user referenced it from that link you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't change alert views. If you really needed you can use [custom ones](https://github.com/kwent/ios-custom-alertview).