# Change UIAlertController selected button color

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uialertcontroller

I have this lines of code:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancelTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    NSLog(@"cancel registration");
}];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

I want to change the cancel button color when is selected. How can I do that?
Please help.

Comment: Did u check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157694/change-button-title-color-in-uialertview

Comment: @jithin I checked this link but the tintColor is changed to default color when the button is selected. My question is about color of button selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancelTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
NSLog(@"cancel registration");
}];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
```

> try setting the tint color *AFTER* you present your alert controller:

```
[self presentViewController: alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
 alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

**Swift**

```
var alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController.alertControllerWithTitle(title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
var cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction.actionWithTitle(cancelTitle, style: .Cancel, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    NSLog("cancel registration")
})
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
```

> try setting the tint color *AFTER* you present your alert controller:

```
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: have a nice day my friend , at the same @Ferrakkem Bhutan , Bhumica answer also correct ,

Comment: if my answer is working fine , give the up vote for the answer ,it is useful for future

Comment: I gave you the up vote when I said "thanks" :) @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the tint color on the view of the `UIAlertController`.

```
 UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancelTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    NSLog(@"cancel registration");
     alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
```

Comment: I wrote this line too, but when the button is selected the tint color is turned to default color.

Comment: it is the bug in iOS 9 and Xcode 7.0.1 , you can check this in Xcode 7.1 and iOS 9.1 and above

Comment: It doesn't work @Anbu.Karthik, I tried this version until to ask the question and I have Xcode 7.1 and iOS 9.1 .

Answer (score -1):

Try this

**Swift**

```
   {
        // Bugfix: iOS9 - Tint not fully Applied without Reapplying
        alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
```

**Objective-C**

```
   {
        // Bugfix: iOS9 - Tint not fully Applied without Reapplying
        alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
```

for more details [Click Here.](https://openradar.appspot.com/22209332)

Comment: this code is for swift not for objective-c :)) @Ferrakkem Bhuiyan