# Styling Xamarin.Foms DisplayAlert

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to change the properties of Xamarin Forms' (Especially for UWP) `DisplayAlert` such as size, text color, button color etc. ? I have been trying to find a solution for this but could not find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Forms DisplayAlert Button TextColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428364/xamarin-forms-displayalert-button-textcolor)

Comment: This isn't off topic....

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom renderers and create the specific-platform alert.

More information:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: There is no example of alerts here.